# 'Extra argument 'id' in call' with Swift struct

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, struct, swift2

I have a Struct in Swift that looks like this:

```
import Foundation

let invalidCharsForFirstCharacter : [Character] = [
     "\\", "_", "-", "!", "'" , "§", "$", "%", "&", "/", "(", ")", "=", "?", ".", ":", ",", ";"
]

struct Event {
    var id : String {
        set {
            if invalidCharsForFirstCharacter.contains(newValue[newValue.startIndex]) {
                self.id = ""
            } else {
                self.id = newValue
            }
        }
        get {
            return self.id
        }
    }

    var name : String
}
```

When I now want to initialize the struct with a call like `let testEvent = Event(id: "id123", name: "name")` Xcode gives me the error *"Extra argument 'id' in call"*.

I use Xcode Version 7.0 (7A218) and Swift 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the message *Extra argument 'id' in call* because your struct doesn't have an initializer with this `id` parameter.

But in your case you can't add this init because your `id` variable has a setter that uses `self`, and you can't use `self` before the struct is fully initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @EricD., you point it out. I remove the getter and setter and add a 'didSet' block:

```
didSet {
        for char in invalidCharsForFirstCharacter {
            if id.hasPrefix("\(char)") {
                id = ""
                break
            }
        }
    }
```